# speed of indexing data.frame row by name in R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, big-o

Is indexing a data.frame row by name (as in `dataFrame["name", ]`) sublinear? Since I have timestamp values as row names, I'm cosidering writing a function tha calculates the row index from the timestamp (assuming  `dataFrame[1, ]` is `O(1)`).

Comment: It might be worth investigating the `data.table` package.

Comment: Or convert it to a time serie using the `xts` package for example....